# Finding the lowest energies of electrons in a box with a delta separator with a tight-binding model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wave-particle-duality, approximations, tight-binding

I am asked to find the two lowest energies of a 1D situation with two electrons in two adjacent $0$-potential wells of width $L$ with infinitely high barriers and a 'coupling potential' of $V(z)=\alpha \delta(z)$ or $V(z)=0$.

I imagine what is meant by 'coupling potential' is just the barrier separating the two wells.

I am asked to use a tight-binding model to approximate the two lowest energies.

However, I am not sure how to do this because to my understanding, the tight-binding model gives an approximate solution to a lone particle in a series of wells, not two interacting particles!

Here is what I know:

- We can expect that the lowest energy states are ones where the electrons are furthest apart, i.e. each in their own separate wells. This minimizes the potential coming from their charge.
- We need to identify kets $|\psi_r\rangle, |\psi_l\rangle$ corresponding to the lowest energy eigenstates of a one-sided version of the problem. I can't figure out how to split the problem up in a meaningful way due to the unignorable interaction between the two electrons in their two wells.
- The answer when the barrier $V(z)=0$ will probably be nonphysical since the two wells aren't separated, so assumptions for using the tight-binding model aren't met.
- The eigenfunctions/values for a particle in a centered well are: $$\phi_n(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[-L/2,L/2]}\sqrt{L/2} \sin(n\pi/L(x+L/2)),\quad E_n=n^2\pi^2\hbar^2/(2mL^2)$$
  This is problematic, since these eigenfunctions are exactly zero on the barrier, which make the inner products in the tight-binding model collapse to 0.
- If $\hat{d}$ gives the distance between the two electrons, the full Hamiltonian looks something like:

$$\hat{H}=(\hat H_{\text{kinetic}}+\hat H_{\text{potential}}+\hat H_{\text{interaction}})=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2(m_e)} \nabla^2 + V+\frac{(e^-)^2}{4\pi \varepsilon_0\hat{d}}$$

Can someone help me continue or correct my understanding?